# What was the concert program for Symphogear Live 2012?

Tags: senki-zesshou-symphogear

Symphogear Live 2012 - the concert for the first season - was, sadly, [not officially videotaped](http://zoid9000.tumblr.com/post/102487159552/do-you-know-if-exist-any-videos-of-symphogear-live). This being the case, I would be very interested to know what the program for the concert was. In particular:

- What was the set list? (i.e. which songs were performed? Given the relatively limited number of Symphogear songs in existence as of the end of season one - 13, by my reckoning - I would hope the answer is "all of them".)
- Did the concert feature any segments of particular interest aside from the vocal performances? (talk segments and so forth, say)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [an official report of the concert (in Japanese)](http://www.symphogear.com/live2012report.html), but [post no.706 on 2chan](http://blog.livedoor.jp/animesong_gamesong/archives/18653976.html) listed the program compactly (*added summary from official report*):

> 1. Synchrogazer (OP theme, sung by Nana Mizuki)
> 2. 1st talk session
>
>    - Character introduction:
>
>      1. Tsubasa Kazanari (Nana Mizuki)
>      2. Hibiki Tachibana (Aoi Yuuki)
>      3. Chris Yukine (Ayahi Takagaki)
>      4. Miku Kohinata (Yuka Iguchi)
>      5. Genjuurou Kazanari (Hideo Ishikawa)
>    - Opening talk
>
> ---
>
> Three-song relay sung by each character
>
> 3. 撃槍・ガングニール - Gekisou Gungnir (Hibiki Tachibana)
> 4. 絶刀・天羽々斬 - Zettou Amenohabakiri (Tsubasa Kazanari)
> 5. 魔弓・イチイバル - Mayumi Ichiibaru (Chris Yukine)
>
> ---
>
> 6. 2nd talk session: live impression by Yuuki, Mizuki, and Takagaki
> 7. 戦姫絶妙ジェスチャークイズ - Senki Zetsumyou Gesture Quiz
>
>    - 2 teams, *Nakayoshi team* (Hibiki &  Miku) and *Elite team* (Tsubasa & Chris)
>    - The topic is [four-character idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yojijukugo)
>    - *Nakayoshi team* went first. Yuuki was imitating a boar and attacked Iguchi. Iguchi answered correctly with 猪突猛進 (headlong)
>    - *Elite team* next. Takagaki flinched as if she was receiving an attack, then kneeled with 1 leg. Mizuki answered with 猪突猛進 (tired and exhausted), but the correct answer was 満身創痍 (full of wounds)
>    - *Nakayoshi team*'s turn again. This time, Iguchi acted as if there were 2 people enjoying something (*kya! kya!*). Yuki answered with 共同作業 (work together) confusedly, but the correct answer was 和気藹々 (warm heartedly)
>    - *Elite team* again, with Mizuki performed each letter of 風林火山 (wind, forest, fire, mountain) and Takagaki answered correctly with ease
>    - Because of the tie, the game was continued
>    - *Nakayoshi team* with Yuki acted and Iguchi answered correctly with 一攫千金(get rich quick)
>    - *Elite team* with Takagaki acted and Mizuki answered correctly with 優柔不断 (indecision)
>    - Sudden death with Ishikawa as the actor and free-for-all style, Takagaki answered correctly with 右往左往 (going right and left, confused)
>    - *Elite team* was given ブドウノイズ印桐箱高級ブドウ (something related to Grape Noise?) for the prize.
>
> **↑ live's first-half ↑**
>
> ---
>
> **↓ live's second-half ↓**
>
> 8. FLIGHT FEATHERS (Tsubasa Kazanari)
> 9. 恋の桶狭間 - Koi no Okehazama (Tsubasa Kazanari sang to a magnolia tree)
> 10. 私ト云ウ 音響キ ソノ先ニ - Watashi to Iu Otohibiki sono Saki ni (Hibiki Tachibana)
> 11. 陽だまりメモリア - Hidamari Memoria (Miku Kohinata)
> 12. 繋いだ手だけが紡ぐもの - Tsunaida Te Dake ga Tsumugu Mono (Chris Yukine)
> 13. Meteor Light (ED theme, sung by Ayahi Takagaki)
>
> **↑ live's second-half ↑**
>
> ---
>
> **↓ encore ↓**
>
> 14. TV Anime 2nd-season announcement
> 15. FIRST LOVE SONG (Hibiki, Tsubasa, and Chris)
> 16. 3rd talk session: closing message

Comment: Thank you! I had actually found the writeup on the official website after I asked the question, but I don't think I would've stumbled across the 2chan post. Bounty for you.